# Getting pins from a saved Google Map into v3 API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a saved google map in 'My Places', with over 100+ pins added for locations around the UK. Is there any way I can avoid having to use the embed feature to display this map on a webpage, sort of calling the saved map by ID via the google API?

Essentially what I want to do is get access to google's new visual refresh and be able to control the settings of the map more with API.

The map link is this: https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?msid=207590858966548688521.0004aa52150024d3431b2&msa=0

Can we parse anything here...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlay the KML output by MyMaps using a [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) in the Google Maps API also:

[your MyMaps data displayed on an API based map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.co.uk%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fie%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D207590858966548688521.0004aa52150024d3431b2)

Updates in MyMaps will (eventually) be reflected on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://mapsengine.google.com I was able to import the maps data and utilise the pins that way. Not ideal, but still some better functionality.